# What technology is this kind of app.js?

Tags: javascript, truffle

This is kind of a meta question because I don't know the name of what I want to search.

After following the [truffle tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop#instantiating-the-contract), I'm working of a file called `app.js` that looks like this:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},

  init: function() {
    $.getJSON(...){
      ...

    )};
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  foo: function() {
    ...
  }
};

$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        App.init();
    });
});
```

I don't know how to set and use global variables, or to call my own functions with callback, and most importantly I don't know **what to search**.

Is this just truffle, or a whole javascript "family" of apps? I've seen similar `app.js` for other projects but it doesn't help with how to search for the information I need.

Comment: maybe etherium contract

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly No, contracts are written in solidity, not JS

Comment: Tutorial is using Web3 (Etherium API written in Javascript), Bootstrap and JQuery.